# Доступ к записям в WordPress с помощью REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

Возникла проблема при разработке клиентского приложения. Есть рыбацкий сайт на WordPress, служащий для бронирования мест. В нём, с помощью некоего плагина добавлено четыре новых вида сущностей - Пруды, Места на прудах, Счета и Заказы. Собственно, прикрепляю картинку для визуального понимания, о чём идёт речь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее. Я разрабатываю приложение, которое взаимодействует с WordPress посредством REST API для получения данных о пользователях, записях, etc. Так же необходимо получать данные записей, типы которого соответствуют видам упомянутым выше. К этим записям нет доступа по умолчанию. Возникает следующий вопрос: какие действия необходимо предпринять для того, чтобы иметь доступ извне к таким записям?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Возникает следующий вопрос: какие действия необходимо предпринять для
> того, чтобы иметь доступ извне к таким записям?

При регистрации кастомных типов контента в `register_post_type` нужно указать `show_in_rest => true`.

Подробнее см https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_post_type#show_in_rest

Comment: А где это нужно менять? В PHP полный ноль, а разработчик куда-то пропал.

Comment: Ну очевидно там, где (с пом чего) созданы эти сущности. В плагине, в файле функций темы..

Comment: Возможно, для плагинов - это какой-то общий файл с известным именем. Ладно. Буду искать. Спасибо.

Comment: Плагины типа [custom post type](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/custom+post+type/). Они бывают 2х типов. 1 Самописные, в которых регистрация прописана в коде. Тогда ищи у себя такой плагин, а нём указанную функцию. 2. Генерирующие кастомные сущности через настройки в админке. Тогда, соответственно, это делается в настройках плагина. Если тема самописная, то в неё может быть интегрирован вар1.

Comment: Да, в плагине обнаружил код, описывающий нужные мне типы. Указал предложенный Вами параметр и всё заработало.